# DataGridView data is not displayed, but after selecting data it is displayed - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Screenshot:

[image]

I have created a DataGridView in windows forms application.
i have bound data with DataTable. I get data but it is not displaying. When i select the row then it is visible.

```
grdPiDetails.DataSource = iDBUtility.GetDataTable("exp_imp_get_all_PI");
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your code...?

Comment: It's in form load method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening probably because the `DataGridViewCell` has `Foreground` color set as `White`

Include this in your `Form_Load` event: [change *myDGV* with your `DataGridView`]

```
myDGV.RowsDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
```

If this won't fix your issue, try @Niraj's solution

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

> First click on DataGridView -> Edit Column -> (Left Side) Select Column (Like First_Name) -> (Right Side) Set DataPropertyName (Like firstname).

Records Will Display.